# SSRS-How to change query based on parameter value when connecting IBM DB2(AS400) as datasource

Tags: db2, ssrs-2008

I have some parameter values in SSRS ,and i am populating the dataset based on these paraemeters .However i have one parameter called Employee with employee name and code values .The first value of this Employee is 'ALL' ,so that when user clicks ALL ,All the employee details are shown .

I want to change my query based on the employee value,i.e if it is "ALL" it is a different where condition and for employee codes a different where condition

I have checked similar questions in stackoverflow ,they are saying to use If condition but i am connecting to AS400 ,and If condition is not being accepted in the query designer .

The issue lies in this part of my query, SLSMCD is salesman code .This query works for ALL Conditon i.e for all employees)

```
                      (SLSMCD IN
                         (SELECT        WEMEMCD
                           FROM            VHTEMPL VHTEMPL_1
                           WHERE        (WEMEMCD = ?) OR
                                                     (WEMTLCD = ?) OR
                                                     (WEMGLCD = ?) OR
                                                     (WEMBHCD = ?) OR
                                                     (WEMTCMCD = ?) OR
                                                     (WEMGCMCD = ?) OR
                                                     (WEMBCMCD = ?) OR
                                                     (WEMHOTLCD = ?) OR
                                                     (WEMHOGLCD = ?) OR
                                                     (WEMHHODCD = ?) OR
                                                     (WEMGHODCD = ?)))
```

Now for individual employee the query should be

```
 (SLSMCD IN
 (SELECT WEMEMCD FROM VHTEMPL VHTEMPL_1 WHERE (WEMEMCD = ?)
```

I tried using AND and OR Conditions grouping things with () .E.g

```
(SLSMCD IN (SELECT WEMEMCD FROM            VHTEMPL VHTEMPL_1
 WHERE        (WEMEMCD = ? and ? <> 'ALL')
```

But SSRS Automatically removes the () and makes it like (WEMEMCD=?) AND (? <>'ALL)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue using expressions in my dataset

In dataset 
go to choose Query parameter 
go to the respective field you want to put condition

```
=IIF(Parameters!PRSalesManCode.Value <> 
"ALL",Parameters!PRSalesManCode.Value,Parameters!PRSalesMan.Value)
```

Here Parameters!PRSalesMan.Value is the value i am sending from ASPX page and it is stored as a hidden paraemeter

Parameters!PRSalesManCode.Value is the selected value in drop down of report

SO i compare with ALL and pass value based on condition

Note : I observed that there is no if concept in AS400,so we cant use it in our query while forming the datset in ssrs
(Not fully sure)